# view_search_results event does not fire in google analytics 4 (GA4)

Tags: google-tag-manager, google-analytics-4

My search result has this URL: mydomain.com/search?query=dog and I have installed and enabled the enhanced measurement. However, the view_search_results does not show in GA4 debug view - only page_view event - any suggestions? Did I setup something wrong? Thanks a lot!

Comment: any update on this?  I have the same issue.